# android: buttons' pressed and non-pressed states

Tags: android, animation, button

I am designing a game in which there are some missiles (which are buttons) falling from the above to the bottom of the screen. At the bottom of the screen, there are 5 targets (which are also buttons).

The game is simple, when the missile overlaps with the targets below, both the missile and the target will perform animation.

The missiles are extending view.

## extended gala view:

### Action for the missile

```
           spot.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation_explosion); 
           alert_progress_icon_giraffe = (AnimationDrawable) spot.getBackground();
           alert_progress_icon_giraffe.start();
           score ++;

           mGame_gala.pressing_animation(a);
```

## Game_gala:

```
public void pressing_animation(int idd_) 
{ 
    btn_up = ((Button) findViewById(idd_));     
    btn_up.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation_press_button); 
    alert_pressing_button = (AnimationDrawable) btn_up.getBackground();
    alert_pressing_button.start();
}
```

## Animation_press_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressing_button" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressing_button_pressed1" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressing_btn1" android:duration="50"/>

</animation-list>
```

### Drawable `pressing_btn1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressing_button_pressed1"
          android:state_pressed="true" />    

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressing_button" />
</selector>
```

## Mechanism of the above:

The bottom targets, without missiles overlapping on top of it, could perform pressed and non-pressed pic when pressed. Yet, when the missiles are on top of the targets, at this moment, 2 buttons are overlapping each other, and only the missiles can perform pressed and non-pressed states pic. So I have implemented the above such that when the missile is pressed, it invokes the `Game_gala` method to make the target makes a pressed state graphics.

## Question:

When the missile comes for the first time, both the missile and the target have completed their pressed effect perfectly. Yet when the second missile hit the same target, only the missile can perform its own animation, the target does not show the "pressed" state graphics.

Yet if the targets are pressed independently, it can show pressed and non-pressed states perfectly even being pressed by the missile before.

How can the above be modified such that whenever there are missiles **repeatedly** hitting the same target, the target will show its pressed state when the missile is pressed?

**In short, I would like to have the 2 overlapping buttons showing pressed states when they are pressed.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether it is because of the btn_up is inflated, it does not get the id of the btn_up after the first time...?

Nevertheless, I have worked out a simple way using `Handler` rather than using `AnimationDrawable`, which is much simplier and bringing the same final effect:

```
public void pressing_animation(int iddd_) 
{       
    btn_up = ((Button) findViewById(iddd_));    
    btn_up.setPressed(true);
    final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
    handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            btn_up.setPressed(false);
        }
    }, 50);
}
```